# How to search for a word in VB?

Tags: algorithm, vb6

I have found a lot of methods for finding words inside strings but what I want to do it to find if the exact word is there.

For example, if I search for **test** and the input is formed of the strings: **test**, **testing**, **a test application**, **newtest**, the program must find only **test** and **a test application** and not the other ones containing that word.

Does anybody know how to do that? Especially in Visual Basic if possible.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far? And is this for VB6 or VB.Net?

Comment: @xxbbcc: I can show you in about 10 hours, now I am at home, I have this problem at the job. I don't have the code I've tried right now.

Comment: @salam, `VB.Net` <> `VBA` <> `vb6`. Pick one!

Comment: Can you define what delimits words? For example, I suspect any white space, but what about symbols such as '-' '&' ',' '.' etc.?

Comment: @hatchet: for delimiting words are used white spaces, commas and dots. For example, aa-bb is considered a single word

Comment: Convert all delimiting characters to spaces, prepend and append a space to the start and end of the string you're searching in, and then search for `" " + targetString + " "`

Comment: If it's vb6 you are asking about, please edit your question to remove the vb.net and vba tags. You should probably also remove the visual-studio tag.

Comment: @hatchet: but how do I do if the word is the first or the last in an array, it will not have any spaces before if it is the first and no space after if it is the last.

Comment: Adding a space to to the beginning and end of the string you're searching in solves that.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the input into an array (or arrays) of words using VB's Split function, and then loop through the words and test if each equals "test".

```
Sub test()

Dim sInput As String
sInput = "test, testing, a test application, newtest"

arInput = Split(sInput, ",")

Dim cMatched As New Collection

For Each sPhrase In arInput
    arWords = Split(sPhrase, " ")
    bMatched = False
    For Each sword In arWords
        If sword = "test" Then bMatched = True
    Next
    If bMatched Then
        cMatched.Add sPhrase
        MsgBox sPhrase
  End If
Next

End Sub
```